# Elixir: when to use 'number' and when to use 'integer'

Tags: elixir

The examples seem to consist of both 'number' and 'integer'. What are the respective situations that they should be used in?

Edit: here is an example of each

```
@type bar :: %{atom => [{binary, integer}]}

def foo(x) when is_number(x), do: x
```

Comment: Could you clarify which examples you are referring to, or what scenarios you are wondering about specifically?

Comment: Without knowing exactly which examples you're referencing my guess would be that 'number' is referring to both floats and integers while integer is specific to that type of number. But that's simply a guess.

Comment: edited the question to include examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number is a more general type which refers to both floats and integers. If you want to check if a value is numeric, but don't care if it's a float or an integer, use number. If you want to enforce a specific type, use integer/float. In your example above you could use `is_integer(x)` or `is_float(x)` instead of `is_number(x)` if you need more specificity.